# Static override / abstract methods - Any good workaround?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract base configuration class and two implementations:

```
public abstract class BaseConfiguration
{
}

public class LoginConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    public LoginConfiguration() 
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class TestConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    public TestConfiguration()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing:
Every specific class type has a explicit filename it points to. This means LoginConfiguration has a filename called "login.xml" and TestConfiguration points to "test.xml".

The filename I would like to use for deserialization later on:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LoginConfiguration login = ReadFromFile<LoginConfiguration>();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static TConfig ReadFromFile<TConfig>() where TConfig : BaseConfiguration
{
    //Something like this needs to be done here:
    string filename = TConfig.GetFilename();

    //Deserialize file and return object
    return Deserialize<TConfig>(filename);
}
```

But I know that you can neither have static overides nor static abstract methods.

What I am currently doing is using the base class to instantiate a new object and read the filename from the instance, but thats very hacky.

```
public abstract class BaseConfiguration
{
    protected BaseConfiguration(string fileName)
    {
        Filename = fileName;
    }

    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public static string GetFilename<TConfig>() where TConfig : BaseConfiguration, new()
    {
        return new TConfig().Filename;
    }
}

//The calling method:
private static TConfig ReadFromFile<TConfig>() where TConfig : BaseConfiguration, new()
{
    string filename = BaseConfiguration.GetFilename<TConfig>();
    //Deserialize file and return object
    return Deserialize<TConfig>(filename);
}
```

My question is now:
Do you have any idea, how I can design it better? Do you have a better Approach?
And wouldn't static abstract methods in C# make sense at this kind of issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your weird design is because your XXXConfiguration class breaks Single Responsibility Principle, it has a property named `filename`, to tell the caller where its data comes from, and other properties to save the loaded data. IMO the XXXConfiguration class should only contain the data, there is no information of its data source.

```
abstract class BaseConfiguration
{
    public string SharedConfigProperty { get; set; }
}

class LoginConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    public string LoginConfigProperty { get; set; }
}

class TestConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    public string TestConfigProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In your original design, `LoginConfiguration` can only have one data-source, it will be a nightmare if you have `login-dev.xml` `login-qa.xml` in the future. Put the load function of configurations in another class is better:

```
class ConfigurationFactory
{
    public static TConfig FromFile<TConfig>() where TConfig : BaseConfiguration
    {
        //you should have a TConfig-fileName mapping
        //e.g. a Dictionary<Type, string>
        //Type is typeof(TConfig) and string is the filename
    }

    public static TConfig FromDataBase<TConfig>() where TConfig : BaseConfiguration
    {
        //as I said, the original design has a lot of restricts
        //what if they change the storage from file to data base?
        //you need to change every derived class, renaming FileName to DataBaseTableName?
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually like that idea, would you store the mapping (Directory<Type,string> directly in the Factory? But still, this will give an exception at runtime and not at compile-time, afaics :) But yeah, the design of my class is an issue, I totally agree. :)

Comment: @Jannik I know the purpose of your original code is to avoid the lack of registration at compile time, that's a correct direction. However we can't check everything when compiling, sometimes we need a balance between design and safety. Leave some work to other developers/QAs and trust them :)

Comment: It is a solo-project, so there is no opportunity to give away work. The main goal is to exercise my skills and to write some neat code. :) Just to let you know: Yesterday I tried to refactor it and found out, I already have a similar class called "ConfigurationManager", which sets and retrieves the configs of my app. I just had to rename it to ConfigurationFactory (a better name imho) and added a mapping like you said. I splitted the factory and mapping into *Factory and *Mapper which has one method Map, which needs a type and returns the filename. Is this satisfying your recommondations?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind a bit of reflection, you could add an attribute to provide the file name:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ConfigFileAttribute : Attribute
{
    ...
}

[ConfigFile("login.xml")]
public class LoginConfiguration 
{
    ...
}
```

Since you already have the type (`TConfig`), you can access the attribute using:

```
var configAttributes = typeof(TConfig).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConfigFileAttribute), false);
```

Of course this does mean that forgetting the attribute would make the read fail.

This is not the "best" solution, but I personally prefer the separate administration of a filename, where the class itself has no interest in it.

Comment: Yeah, I had the exact same thing in mind and was about to try it out, but I rethought this and figured, it's a bit safer to use my way, because I could forget the attribute. :) But sure, thats another possibility. :)

Comment: Make a unit test that checks every class derived from `BaseConfiguration` and fail if the attribute is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I sometimes wish for the ability to specify a contract 'if you extend this class then you need to provide a static method with this signature', but unfortunately that doesn't exist.

It's not *that* much neater, but I would probably make a static map of the filenames like this:

```
public abstract class BaseConfiguration
{
    static BaseConfiguration()
    {
        Filenames = new Dictionary<Type, string>
        {
            { typeof(LoginConfiguration), "login.xml" },
            { typeof(TestConfiguration), "test.xml" },
        };
    }

    private static Dictionary<Type, string> Filenames { get; }

    public static string GetFilename<TConfig>() where TConfig : BaseConfiguration
    {
        return Filenames[typeof(TConfig)];
    }
}
```

The advantages being that you have all the filenames in one place and that you don't need to allocate an instance to get the filename.

Comment: The design is wrong because base class knows about the concrete classes. I would suggest having this dictionary outside base class, then it would make more sense.

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas: That's a very academic argument to make for a *configuration* class. It's not like this is a public facing API

Comment: Well I would not call it academic, it is just a proper engineering approach. Configuration class has its own concern of providing user/app based settings, though reading that config is a concern of a component which knows how to interact with file system (in specific case), and maybe even deserialization component.If you would go for additional persistence level in database, you would create even more code smell with current design. File name should not be in config base class imho. Peace.

Comment: It would take all of five seconds to copy the code to some other class if there ends up being value to that. It's a suggestion for a solution direction on stackoverflow, not a fully engineered subsystem of some real world project. Nothing you say is *wrong* but I feel you've gone way past the context of this question and answer.

Comment: This is a very good idea, but as Vidas pointed out, my Base class doesnt know the configuration implementations, they are in different layers. :)

Comment: @Jannik: Yeah I think his suggestion to put the map in some other class is fine? I like the attribute answer too though, in retrospect I'd consider that first.

Comment: @Jannik It's better if  the loading function is not part of the configuration,put it in a factory, the base class shouldn't know its derives, but the factory can.